# Bring image to front onclick in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, bringtofront

I have made a demo for a photocollage,And i have done almost with it,But i want to bring an image to front on its click,I have tried this as below 
code,But its not working,My code is as below:I have attached my layout xml code and accordingly java code,Please help me to figure it out,Thank you in advance
**xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:splitMotionEvents="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn_save" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collageBgView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="#FFD4B081" />

            <com.example.collageapp.CollageView
                android:id="@+id/collageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/daffodils" />

            <com.example.collageapp.CollageView
                android:id="@+id/collageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/green" />

            <com.example.collageapp.CollageView
                android:id="@+id/collageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/hawaii" />

            <com.example.collageapp.CollageView
                android:id="@+id/collageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sunset" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ce000000"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="SAVE"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**code**

findViewById(R.id.collageView1).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                collageView1.bringToFront();

                collageView1.invalidate();
                collageView2.invalidate();
                collageView3.invalidate();
                collageView4.invalidate();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Try to call `parent.invalidate();` (parent = highest level view) after `collageView1.bringToFront();`.

Comment: @Rami-Please see my updated code,I have tried as per suggested,but no change..can you help e some more.

Comment: @Rami-Please see my code,Its not working..:(

Comment: what do you mean by "image to front on its click" ?

Comment: @DavidJhons-its if i have four images (to make a collage), then last image which is at the bottom of all other images should be came to front on its click event.